# find -exec + vs find | xargs: which one to choose?

Tags: bash, find, pipe, xargs

I understand that the `-exec` can take a `+` option to mimic the behaviour of `xargs`. Is there any situation where you'd prefer one form over the other?

I personally tend to prefer the first form, if only to avoid using a pipe. I figure surely the developers of `find` must've done the appropriate optimizations. Am I correct?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You might want to chain calls to find (once, when you learned, that it is possible, which might be today). This is, of course, only possible as long as you stay in find. Once you pipe to xargs it's out of scope.

Small example, two files a.lst and b.lst:

```
cat a.lst
fuddel.sh
fiddel.sh

cat b.lst
fuddel.sh
```

No trick here - simply the fact that both contain "fuddel" but only one contains "fiddel".

Assume we didn't know that. We search a file which matches 2 conditions:

```
find -exec grep -q fuddel {} ";" -exec grep -q fiddel {} ";" -ls
192097    4 -rw-r--r--   1 stefan   stefan         20 Jun 27 17:05 ./a.lst
```

Well, maybe you know the syntax for grep or another program to pass both strings as condition, but that's not the point. Every program which can return true or false, given a file as argument, can be used here - grep was just a popular example.

And note, you may follow **find -exec** with other find commands, like **-ls** or **-delete** or something similar. Note, that delete not only does rm (removes files), but rmdir (removes directories) too.

Such a chain is read as an AND combination of commands, as long as not otherwise specified (namely with an `-or` switch (and parens (which need masking))).

So you aren't leaving the find chain, which is a handy thing. I don't see any advantage in using -xargs, since you have to be careful in passing the files, which is something find doesn't need to do - it automatically handles passing each file as a single argument for you.

If you believe you need some masking for finds [{} braces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which), feel free to visit my question which asks for evidence. My assertion is: You don't.

Comment: This post has opened my eyes to a new way of using `find`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I don't see any advantage in using -xargs". What's the `-exec` way of doing `xargs -P4` so that three of four cores don't stay idle?

Comment: @DamianYerrick: End the -exec command not in ";" but with a + (/plus sign).

Answer (score 28):

Safely piping file names to `xargs` requires that your `find` supports the `-print0` option and your `xargs` has the corresponding option to read it (`--null` or `-0`).  Otherwise, filenames with unprintable characters or backslashes or quotes or whitespace in the name may cause unexpected behavior.  On the other hand, `find -exec {} +` is in the [POSIX `find` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), so it is portable, and it is about as safe as `find -print0 | xargs -0`, and definitely safer than `find | xargs`.  I'd recommend *never* doing `find | xargs` without `-print0`.

Comment: A notable exception to the portability of `find … -exec … {} +` is OpenBSD, which only acquired this feature with version 5.1 released in 2012. All BSDs have had `-print0` for several years, even OpenBSD (though it resisted that feature for a while too). Solaris, on the other hand, sticks to POSIX features, so you get `-exec +` and no `-print0`.

Comment: `-print0` is a pain and though you can argue `xargs --delimiter "\n"` isn't equivalent, I've never once used the former after discovering the latter.

Comment: I don't see how `-0` is more of a pain than `--delimiter "\n"`.

Comment: In addition to `-0`, GNU `xargs` needs `-r` to avoid running the command if there's no input.

Comment: Another problem of `| xargs -r0 cmd` is that `cmd`'s stdin is affected (depending on the `xargs` implementation, it's `/dev/null` or the pipe.

Answer (score 11):

If you use the `-exec ... ;` form (remembering to escape the semicolon), you're running the command once per filename. If you use `-print0 | xargs -0`, you run multiple commands per filename. You should definitely use the `-exec +` form, which puts multiple files in a single command line and is much faster when a large number of files is involved.

A big plus of using `xargs` is the ability to run multiple commands in parallel using `xargs -P`. On multi-core systems, that can provide huge time savings.

Comment: You meant `-P` instead of `-p`.  Keep in mind `xargs -P` is not in the POSIX standard, whereas `find -exec {} +` is, which is important if you are going for portability.

Comment: @Alexios You don't have to escape the plus sign, because it does not have a special meaning for the shell: `find /tmp/ -exec ls "{}" +` works just fine.

Comment: Corrent, of course. I've been escaping everything after the `-exec` for so long (I'm a masochist, I don't even use quotes to escape `{}`, I always type `\{\}`; don't ask), everything looks like it must be escaped now.

Comment: @Alexios: If you find an example (except from being a masochist) where the masking of the braces is useful, please provide it as an answer [to my question here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8647/4485) - afaik this hint is outdated and only a relict in the manpage. I've never seen an example where `find /tmp/ -exec ls {} +` wouldn't work.

Comment: For me, this is muscle memory formed in the days of SunOS 4. Since I've been doing it for years, I completely failed to notice when `bash` started accepting the braces verbatim. I'm pretty sure at least one of the old shells I've used threw hissy fits if the braces weren't escaped.

Comment: @Alexios - To clarify, do you mean that if the command -exec mv {} \; is run, it would execute as mv file1, mv file2 and so on? In contrast xargs -0 mv could result in xargs mv file``, xargs mv file2` and thus multiple commands?

Answer (score 10):

Concerning performance I thought that `-exec … +` would simply be better because it's a single tool doing all the work but [a part of GNU findutil's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html#Deleting-Files) says that `-exec … +` might be less efficient in some cases:

> *[find with `-exec … +`]* can be less efficient than some uses of `xargs`; for example `xargs` allows new command lines to be built up while the previous command is still executing, and allows you to specify a number of commands to run in parallel. However, the `find ... -exec ... +` construct has the advantage of wide portability. GNU findutils did not support ‘`-exec ... +`’ until version 4.2.12 *[January 2005]*; one of the reasons for this is that it already had the ‘`-print0`’ action in any case.

I wasn't exactly sure what that meant so I asked in the chat where [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert) explained it as:

> `find` probably could continue to search for the next batch of files while the `-exec … +` is running, but it doesn't.
>   `find … | xargs …` does, because then the find is a different process, and it keeps running until the pipe buffer fills up

(Formatting by me.)

So there is that. But if performance really matters you would have to do realistic benchmarking or rather even ask yourself whether you even would want to use shell for such cases.

Here on this site I think it's better to advise people to use the `-exec … +` form whenever possible because just because it's simpler and for the reasons mentioned in the other answers here (e.g. handling strange filenames without having to think much).