# How can I get all the ENV keys from .rb and .yml files in a directory tree?

Tags: regular-expression

I would like to find a way to get the unique keys that are used inside `.rb` and `.yml` files. These keys are used inside the hash `ENV`. So, there are files that contain things like:

```
ENV['key']
```

in multiple lines and at various positions within their lines. Also, those might appear multiple times within those lines.

So, If I have the file:

```
blah blah blah ENV['key1'] blah blah blah ENV['key2']
blah blah blah ENV['key2']
blah blah
ENV['key3'] blah blah ENV['key2']
```

then I would like to get the list:

```
key1
key2
key3
```

I have managed to do this:

```
find . -iname "*.rb" -o -iname "*.yml" | xargs egrep 'ENV\[.(.*).\]'
```

but I do not know how to actually get the keys.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `-o` flag to `grep` to get only the matching parts of the line:

```
find . '(' -iname "*.rb" -o -iname "*.yml" ')' -exec grep -o -E 'ENV\[.(.*).\]' {} + | sort -u | cut -d'[' -f 2 | tr -d "']"
```

Also, I highly recommend using the `-exec` flag to `find` instead of piping to `xargs`:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)
- [Find -exec + vs find | xargs. Which one to choose?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41740/find-exec-vs-find-xargs-which-one-to-choose).

Comment: @jayhandren are you sure this one processes all files? I have tried that and works only with the "*.yml" files. Does not process the "*.rb" files.

Comment: The logic on `find` is incorrect, and needs to instead be `find . \( -iname "*.rb" -o -iname "*.yml" \) -exec ...`

Comment: thanks to both of you, corrected. @p.matsinopoulos it should work correctly now.

Comment: I think it does not work if there are 2 or more occurrences of ENV inside the same line.

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos it does work. if there are multiple matches on the same line, `grep -o` will print each match separately.