# How to replace a hash pattern inside file and directory names

Tags: shell, rename, mv, pattern-matching, mmv

I've just backed up the notes I have in [Notion](https://www.notion.so/), and they use hashcodes in the notes names to make them unique apparently.

For example, this is might be a note-folder with some notes:

```
Archive e74f698cb73b42c790d08999bdbe47e4
├── Note 1 cda63bef095a493f9847d516cf34fa5f.md
├── Note 2 dda63bef095a493f9847d516cf34fa5f.md
```

(Sometimes there's also a `.csv` file for tables)

I was trying to use a regex like `[a-z0-9]{32}` to replace the pattern, but was having difficulty making it work with `s/`:

```bsh
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/[a-z0-9]{32}//g'
```

(I'm not sure I really understand what the purpose of `-print0` and `-0` is.)

The code above only works for files, but I've also tried to use something like `mv $f ${f:0:-34}` though I couldn't make it work either. Is there a way of making this replacing with only one line for both files and folders, without `for`s?

I've tried many other answers on StackOverflow about this but almost all I've found so far either only deal with files or with fixed words as patterns.

I wanted to use the Mass-Move command line tool (`mmv`), but there's no official distribution for Arch Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: the following assumes that you are using the Perl-based `rename` command, as implied by your observation that `rename 's/[a-z0-9]{32}//g'` "works for files".* See

- [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename)

---

To find directories as well as files, you need to remove the `-type f` restriction.

In addition you will need to prevent directories from being renamed before their containing files - with GNU `find`, that may be done using `-depth` to specify depth-first traversal.

Finally, you need to make sure that the `rename` command operate only on the file basename rather than its path components - your `rename` implementation may provide an option to do that (ex. `-d`, `--filename`, `--nopath`, `--nofullpath`) but you can also invoke `rename` directly from `find` using the `-execdir` action.

So

```bsh
find . -depth -execdir rename -n 's/ [a-z0-9]{32}//' {} +
```

(remove the `-n` once you are satisfied with the proposed substitutions). Note that you don't need the `g` replacement flag to replace a single instance of the pattern per file.

You could also consider replacing `[a-z0-9]` with `[[:xdigit:]]`.

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)
- [find -exec + vs find | xargs: which one to choose?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41740/find-exec-vs-find-xargs-which-one-to-choose)

Comment: Could you also provide a brief explanation for `{}` and `+`?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro I have added a link which explains them better than I can

Comment: I'm getting back a `rename: not enough arguments` from the code above, both with or without `-n`. Given that there's a space right before the hashcodes, shouldn't we also eliminate it with the pattern?

Comment: Nice additional resources, thanks.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro are you sure you are using the Perl-based `rename` command rather than the `util-linux` one? Regarding the extra space, I just used the pattern that you suggested - of course you may remove the space as well if you wish.

Comment: I hadn't realized my question had that info implied. I've just installed `perl-rename` with pacman and the does indeed work as expected. I've received some weird messages (`perl-rename: cannot create `./Untitled Database ': Directory not empty` and `perl-rename: cannot create` and `./The Cabal Valves Design Process For Creating Half- ': Directory not empty`), but overall everything seems to have worked.

Comment: [This question had been originally asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66746226/4756173) actually, but some mods closed it and I had to reask it here. They've now reopened it there, do you want to answer it again there?