# Sorting files according to size recursively

Tags: command-line, find, ls

I need to find the largest files in a folder. 
How do I scan a folder recursively and sort the contents by size?

I have tried using `ls -R -S`, but this lists the directories as well. 
I also tried using `find`.

Comment: Do you want to list the files in each subdirectory separately or do you want to find all files in all subdirs and list them by size irrespective of which subdir they are in? Also, what do you mean by "directory" and "folder"? You seem to be using them to describe different things.

Comment: Are you saying that you just want to list the files in a given directory as well as the files in its sub-directories without showing just the sub-directories? Please try and clean up you question, it's not very clear.

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158289/finding-largest-file-recursively

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can also do this with just `du`. Just to be on the safe side I'm using this version of `du`:

```
$ du --version
du (GNU coreutils) 8.5
```

The approach:

```
$ du -ah <some DIR> | grep -v "/$" | sort -rh
```

#### Breakdown of approach

The command `du -ah DIR` will produce a list of all the files and directories in a given directory `DIR`. The `-h` will produce human readable sizes which I prefer. If you don't want them then drop that switch. I'm using the `head -6` just to limit the amount of output!

```
$ du -ah ~/Downloads/ | head -6
4.4M    /home/saml/Downloads/kodak_W820_wireless_frame/W820_W1020_WirelessFrames_exUG_GLB_en.pdf
624K    /home/saml/Downloads/kodak_W820_wireless_frame/easyshare_w820.pdf
4.9M    /home/saml/Downloads/kodak_W820_wireless_frame/W820_W1020WirelessFrameExUG_GLB_en.pdf
9.8M    /home/saml/Downloads/kodak_W820_wireless_frame
8.0K    /home/saml/Downloads/bugs.xls
604K    /home/saml/Downloads/netgear_gs724t/GS7xxT_HIG_5Jan10.pdf
```

Easy enough to sort it smallest to biggest:

```
$ du -ah ~/Downloads/ | sort -h | head -6
0   /home/saml/Downloads/apps_archive/monitoring/nagios/nagios-check_sip-1.3/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ldaps
0   /home/saml/Downloads/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2013.04.06/0/index/write.lock
0   /home/saml/Downloads/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2013.04.06/0/translog/translog-1365292480753
0   /home/saml/Downloads/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2013.04.06/1/index/write.lock
0   /home/saml/Downloads/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2013.04.06/1/translog/translog-1365292480946
0   /home/saml/Downloads/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2013.04.06/2/index/write.lock
```

Reverse it, biggest to smallest:

```
$ du -ah ~/Downloads/ | sort -rh | head -6
10G /home/saml/Downloads/
3.8G    /home/saml/Downloads/audible/audio_books
3.8G    /home/saml/Downloads/audible
2.3G    /home/saml/Downloads/apps_archive
1.5G    /home/saml/Downloads/digital_blasphemy/db1440ppng.zip
1.5G    /home/saml/Downloads/digital_blasphemy
```

Don't show me the directory, just the files:

```
$ du -ah ~/Downloads/ | grep -v "/$" | sort -rh | head -6 
3.8G    /home/saml/Downloads/audible/audio_books
3.8G    /home/saml/Downloads/audible
2.3G    /home/saml/Downloads/apps_archive
1.5G    /home/saml/Downloads/digital_blasphemy/db1440ppng.zip
1.5G    /home/saml/Downloads/digital_blasphemy
835M    /home/saml/Downloads/apps_archive/cad_cam_cae/salome/Salome-V6_5_0-LGPL-x86_64.run
```

If you want to exclude *all directories* from the output, you can use a trick with the presence of a dot character. This assumes that your directory names do not contain dots, and that the files you are looking for do. Then you can filter out the directories with `grep -v '\s/[^.]*$'`:

```
$ du -ah ~/Downloads/ | grep -v '\s/[^.]*$' | sort -rh | head -2
1.5G    /home/saml/Downloads/digital_blasphemy/db1440ppng.zip
835M    /home/saml/Downloads/apps_archive/cad_cam_cae/salome/Salome-V6_5_0-LGPL-x86_64.run
```

If you just want the list of smallest to biggest, but the top 6 offending files you can reverse the sort switch, drop (`-r`), and use `tail -6` instead of the `head -6`.

```
$ du -ah ~/Downloads/ | grep -v "/$" | sort -h | tail -6
835M    /home/saml/Downloads/apps_archive/cad_cam_cae/salome/Salome-V6_5_0-LGPL-x86_64.run
1.5G    /home/saml/Downloads/digital_blasphemy
1.5G    /home/saml/Downloads/digital_blasphemy/db1440ppng.zip
2.3G    /home/saml/Downloads/apps_archive
3.8G    /home/saml/Downloads/audible
3.8G    /home/saml/Downloads/audible/audio_books
```

Comment: The `grep -v "/$"` part doesn't seem to be doing what you expected, as the directories don't have a slash appended.  Does anyone know how to exclude directories from results?

Comment: @JanekWarchol - what version of coreutils are you using?

Comment: I'm on 8.13.  But anyway, the output in your answer doesn't have trailing `/`s either - for example `/home/saml/Downloads/audible` seems to be a directory, but it doesn't have a slash.  Only `/home/saml/Downloads/` has a slash, but that's probably because you wrote it with a slash when specifying the argument for initial `du`.

Comment: @JanekWarchol - Look at the 5th text box. The grep is just to filter the `~/Downloads/` bit out. As you've stated, it's just to filter out the argument of `~/Downloads` when `du` processes it. I changed the word directories to directory since I think that's ultimately what was causing the confusion. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @JanekWarchol - incidentally to omit the directories you'll have to change tactics and use `find` to generate a list of files only and then have `du` tally them up.

Comment: This finds dirs also

Comment: This doesn't list just files, but also lists directories :(

Comment: du --version in not an option for me, however the approach does work

Comment: building on that solution, and the solution offered on this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22432/getting-size-with-du-of-files-only, I was able to yield a result with files only with the following command:  `find . -type f -exec du -ah {} + | grep -v "/$" | sort -rh`

Comment: @flochtililoch Super answer! It works for me :)

Comment: Use `du --apparent-size` to view the length of the file in bytes (not the size taken on disk).

Comment: @JanWarchoł I could not find any way for `du` to provide a different output for directory (`-S` changes their size, not the output format). So I resorted to a workaround that assumes that your directory names do not have any dots in them, and that the files you care about do. In that case you can replace the non-working `grep -v '/$'` by `grep -v '\s/[^.]*$'`. And you have to make sure you specify DIR as an absolute path, so there is no dot in there.

Comment: How about listing only directories, I'm not interested in files.

Answer (score 40):

If you want to find all files in the current directory and its sub directories and list them according to their size (without considering their path), and assuming none of the file names contain newline characters, with GNU `find`, you can do this:

```
find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n
```

From `man find` on a GNU system:

```
   -printf format
          True; print format  on  the  standard  output,
          interpreting  `\'  escapes and `%' directives.
          Field widths and precisions can  be  specified
          as  with the `printf' C function.  Please note
          that many of the  fields  are  printed  as  %s
          rather  than  %d, and this may mean that flags
          don't work as you  might  expect.   This  also
          means  that  the `-' flag does work (it forces
          fields to be  left-aligned).   Unlike  -print,
          -printf  does  not add a newline at the end of
          the string.  The escapes and directives are:

          %p     File's name.
          %s     File's size in bytes.
```

From `man sort`:

```
   -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac unfortunately, shows: find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Comment: @RomanGaufman yes, that's why the answer specifies ***GNU*** find. If you install the GNU tools on your Mac, it will work there too.

Comment: You can also use "%P" (uppercase) which is: "File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed". In this case it would remove the "./" at the beginning of each path.

Answer (score 15):

Try the following command:

```
ls -1Rhs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -hr | head -n20
```

It'll list top-20 biggest files in the current directory recursively.

Note: The option `-h` for `sort` is not available on OSX/BSD, so you've to install `sort` from `coreutils` (e.g. via `brew`) and apply the local bin path to `PATH`, e.g.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH" # Add a "gnubin" for coreutils.
```

Alternatively use:

```
ls -1Rs | sed -e "s/^ *//" | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -nr | head -n20
```

---

For the biggest directories use `du`, e.g.:

```
du -ah . | sort -rh | head -20
```

or:

```
du -a . | sort -rn | head -20
```

Comment: Perfect, this is the first solution that works on Mac and doesn't show directories :) - thank you!

Comment: how filter to show only file with number of lines >= X ? (X = 0 for exemple)

Answer (score 10):

This will find all files recursively, and sort them by size. It prints out all file sizes in kb, and rounds down so you may see 0 KB files, but it was close enough for my uses, and works on OSX.

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -la | awk '{print int($5/1000) " KB\t" $9}' | sort -n -r -k1`

Comment: worked on Ubuntu 14.04 too!

Comment: This lists directories, not just files :(

Comment: @RomanGaufman - thanks for the feedback! from my tests, `find . -type f` finds files... it works recursively, you're right, but it lists all the files it finds, not the directories themselves

Comment: Xargs has been used in the 1980s. It is a bad idea since 1989 when execplus has been introduced by David Korn.

Comment: Great command but one problem: It does not handle filenames well with spaces. Only the part up until the first space will be printed as of `$9`. 

I tried to improve on this by printing ranges $9-end. I ended up with: `find "$path" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -la | awk '{for (i=5; i<NF; i++) { if (i == 5) { printf int($i/1024) " KiB\t" } else if (i >= 9 ) {  printf $i " " } }; if (NF >= 5) print $NF; }' | sort -n -r -k1`. It seems to work, but feedback is much welcome to make this a bit more concise

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution for Mac/Linux which skips directories:

```
find . -type f -exec du -h {} \; | sort -h
```

Answer (score 5):

With `zsh`, you'd find the largest file (in terms of apparent size like the size column  in `ls -l` output, not disk usage) with:

```
ls -ld -- **/*(DOL[1])
```

For the 6 largest ones:

```
ls -ld -- **/*(DOL[1,6])
```

To sort those by file size, you can use `ls`'s `-S` option. Some `ls` implementations also have a `-U` option for `ls` not to sort the list (as it's already sorted by size by `zsh` here).

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in `BSD` or `OSX` is

```
$ du -ah simpl | sort -dr | head -6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an incredibly commmon need for a variety of reasons (I like finding the most recent backup in a directory), and is a surprisingly simple task.

I'm going to provide a Linux solution that uses the find, xargs, stat, tail, awk, and sort utilities.

Most people have provided some unique answers, but I prefer mine because it properly handles filenames, and the use case can easily be changed (modify stat, and sort arguments)

I'll also provide a Python solution that should let you use this functionality even on Windows

## Linux command line solution

### Recursively return entire list of only files from a directory, sorted by file size

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} stat -c '%s %n' {} | sort -n
```

#### Same as before, but this time, return the largest file.

```
# Each utility is split on a new line to help 
# visualize the concept of transforming our data in a stream
find . -type f -print0 | 
xargs -0 -I{} stat -c '%s %n' {} | 
sort -n | 
tail -n 1 |
awk '{print $2}'
```

#### Same exact Pattern, but now select the newest file instead of largest

```
# (Notice only the first argument of stat changed for new functionality!)
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} stat -c '%Y %n' {} | 
sort -n | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Explanation:

1. find: Recursively finds all files from current directory, and prints them out with a null character
2. xargs: utility to execute commands using arguments provided from standard input. For every line of output, we want to run the stat utility on that file
3. stat: Stat is an all around awesome command that has so many use cases. I am printing out two columns, the first column being the block size (%s), and the second column being the file name (%n)
4. sort: Sort the results with the numeric switch. Since the first argument is an integer, our results will be sorted properly
5. tail: Only select the last line of output (since the list is sorted, this is the largest file!)
6. awk: Select the second column, which contains the filename, and is the largest file in a recursive directory.

## Python solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys
files = list()
for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for filename in filenames:
        realpath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        files.append(realpath)
files_sorted_by_size = sorted(files, key = lambda x: os.stat(x).st_size)
largest_file = files_sorted_by_size[-1]
print(largest_file)
```

This script takes a little big longer to explain, but essentially if you save that as a script, it will search through the first argument provided on the command line, and return the largest file in that directory. The script does no error checking, but it should give you an idea of how to approach this in Python, which gives you a nice platform independent way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try below command with sort option to have folders with size in ascending order

`du -sh * | sort -sh`

Comment: there's no need for the `-s` in `sort`. or?

Answer (score 0):

Variant of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22432/getting-size-with-du-of-files-only) from a similar question

```
find . -type f -exec du -ah {} + | sort -rh | more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | numfmt --to=iec | sort -hr | head
```

- `find -type f` finds all files under current directory, recursively
- `-printf '%s %p\n'`: for each file it prints file size in bytes and file name, separated by space, with newline
- `numfmt --to=iec` formats the first field (file size) in human readable format (with K, M, G suffixes) and keep the file name unchanged
- `sort -hr` sorts in reverse numerically order all lines, understanding human readable suffixes
- `head` prints only the first 10 lines

Answer (score -1):

Something that works on any platform except AIX and HP-UX is:

```
find . -ls | sort +6 | tail
```