# VMware Player update filled up half of 27.5 GB disk. I need to find files and delete them

Tags: disk-usage, vmware

I installed VMware-Player-3.1.6-744570.i386 on Ubuntu 11.4.  The 27.5 GB disk was about 45% full.  I then used VMware-Player to form a virtual machine for Centos, using ISO files for CentOS-6.5-i386.  I had done this on an old laptop, that also had Ubuntu 11.4 installed, and centos ran fine in the VM.

However, in both cases, when I installed centos VMware-Player asked me if I wanted to install an update.  It was taking too long on the old laptop, which tends to overheat so I declined to do so on the laptop.  However, I decided to let the update run overnight on the desktop.  When I came down in the morning, the update was still running and there was only 1.5 GB left on the HD.  I used the disk usage analyzer and found that most of the disk space being used was in mu home directory.  However, when I went to my home directory and ran

```
sudo du | sort -n
```

the only recently update directory with heavy disk usage was the directory with centos ISOs and it was only taking up 4.8 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to see the files based on their size, you can try the below command.

```
du -ah /home | grep -v "/$" | sort -h | tail -6
```

The above command will give the top 6 files which occupy the space. Then probably, you can decide whether those files are needed or to be deleted.

I had a similar issue where I was in need to find the files that occupy more space and more details of that question can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94688/rhel-gdm-could-not-write-to-authorization-file).

As per the suggestions in the answer, *I would use one of the answers from this question*, [sorting files according to size recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88065/sorting-files-according-to-size-recursively/88069#88069) *that shows you the top 10 largest files on your system*.