# Finding largest file recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script, recursive

I am trying to find the largest file in a directory recursively. If there is a subdirectory inside of that directory the function needs to go inside that directory and check to see if the largest file is there. Once the largest file is found the output is displayed with the relative path name and the name and size of the largest file.

EX:

```
dude@shell2 (~...assignment/solutions) % bash maxfile.sh ~/test
class/asn
dude.h.gch: 9481628
```

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

recursiveS() {
    for d in *; do
        if [ -d $d ]; then
            (cd $d; echo $(pwd)/$line; du -a; recursiveS;)
        fi
    done
}
recursiveS
```

I have been stuck for a while now. I cannot implement this by pipelining a number of existing Unix tools. Any ideas would be nice!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522269/bash-how-to-find-the-largest-file-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories

Comment: to go in only subdirs:    `for d in */ .[^.]*/` ; do ...`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

use `find` (here assuming GNU `find`) to output file names with the file size. sort. print out the largest one.

```
find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -1
```

That assumes file paths don't contain newline characters.

---

Using a loop in `bash` with the GNU implementation of `stat`:

```
shopt -s globstar
max_s=0
for f in **; do
  if [[ -f "$f" && ! -L "$f" ]]; then
    size=$( stat -c %s -- "$f" )
    if (( size > max_s )); then
      max_s=$size
      max_f=$f
    fi
  fi
done
echo "$max_s $max_f"
```

This will be significantly slower than the find solution. That also assumes that file names don't end in newline characters and will skip hidden files and not descend into hidden directories.

If there's a file called `-` in the current directory, the size of the file open on stdin will be considered.

Beware that versions of `bash` prior to 4.3 followed symbolic links when descending the directory tree.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I appreciate the help. I am trying to get use to programming in shell. I do not know a whole lot right now so I appreciate you telling me what is happening with that line of code.

Comment: Quick question: Out of curiosity is there a way to do it without piping commands? I am curious because every example I have seen has used piping of some kind.

Comment: I'm sure there are other ways to do it. The UNIX philosophy is that tools should be single-purpose, and to chain them together so the output of one command is fed into the input of the next.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: For specific help on that command: `man find`, `man sort`, `man tail`

Comment: @user2419571: `tail -n 1 <(sort -n <(find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n"))` ;)

Comment: Nice answer. But is the `-printf` option a gnu extension? I can't find it in POSIX docs, and my version of BSD `find` doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: I believe the (main) goal of the assignment is to use recursion?.. this answer is iterative.

Comment: You could even pipe the result to the mail command like this `find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -10 | mail -e -s "ten biggest files" my@email.com` and make it a cronjob to monitor say on a weekly basis

Answer (score 21):

This command helps to list out defined size too.

```
find . -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Comment: This is the first one to work for me on Unix (MacOS)

Answer (score 10):

This works on BSD/macOS and uses fast but non-POSIX `-ls` extension to `find` utility:

```
find . -type f -ls | sort -k7 -r | head -n 3
```

This is slower but may work on POSIX systems where `-ls` extension is not available in `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -al {} \; | sort -k5 -r | head -n3
```

How it works:

- `find` is a powerful file search utility that will show you results based on a given query explained below.
- `find .` will search in current working directory.
- `find . -type f` will search only for a specified file type "f" that is a regular file (it means it will skip directories, special files, links, sockets, etc).
- `-ls` switch will instruct `find` display full information about files found. However, according to man on BSD system, it is an extension to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 ("POSIX.1") standard and may not be available on all platforms.
- Alternatively if `-ls` extension is not available on your system you may `-exec .. {} \;` with `ls -al` command and use 5th field to sort the results. `{}` means the file name that has been found. `\;` encloses the `-exec` command.
- `|` Unix symbol means "pipe" that is will redirect output from one program to input of another program. It will send `find` program output text as inpurt to `sort` program.
- `sort` is a sorting utility. It gets lines of data and then sort those lines ascending order as result.
- `sort -k7` means take 7th field as the sorting parameter value. Parameters are split by spaces. 7th parameter is the file size produced by the `find` utility. If you use `-exec ls -al {} \;` instead of `-ls` then you will use 5th field `-k5` to sort.
- `-r` tells `sort` to use reverse sorting that is put biggest first. Because we want to see biggest files first.
- In addition you can also pipe (`|`) output of the sort to `head` utility that will only show three first lines (as instructed with `-n 3`) of the resulting output if you do not really want to see hundrends of the lines.

Long story short: Use `find` to find recursively regular files only starting search in currently working directory, then display full information about that file using `-ls` extension (or execute `ls -al`). Later on pass the results from `find` to `sort` using unix pipe `|` and make it sort biggest first based on the 7th (or 5th) field. In addition you can limit results to `n` lines using `head` utility.

I mean "use brainz" to make you read "man" and search for solutions offline yourself that will train you in problems solving from scratch :-)

Comment: Not really working on MacOS as it fails to return size correctly and returns a huge number of columns.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`, for the biggest regular file:

```
ls -ld -- **/*(.DOL[1])
```

(of course you can replace `ls -ld --` with any command. If using GNU `ls` or compatible see also the `-h` option for *human readable sizes*)

- `.`: only *regular* files (not directories, symlinks, devices, fifos...)
- `D`: include hidden ones and descend into hidden dirs
- `OL`: reverse-ordered by size (`L`ength).
- `[1]`: only the first match.

If there are ties, you'll get any one of them at random. If you want the first in alphabetical order, add an extra `on` (`o`rder by `n`ame) to sort ties alphabetically.

Note that it considers the files size, not disk usage.

Comment: ... I start to believe that you are on zsh's payroll ;) (which it very well could be?). zsh is unfortunately not available on all systems...

Comment: Possible to get the first ten files? (Without doing something stupid like a loop)

Comment: @Wowfunhappy replace `[1]` with `[1,10]`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)' response, I wanted to add the following notes (I am unable to comment):

1. To get the smallest regular file, use `o` instead of `O`:

```bsh
ls -ld -- **/*(.DoL[1])
```

2. You can filter by a concrete (or several) extensions by appending it/them to the `**/*` wildcard:

```bsh
ls -ld -- **/*.png(.DoL[1])
ls -ld -- **/*.{png, jpg}(.DoL[1]) # this will give two results, one per extension
```