# List Top 20 Largest Files in a Specific Directory

Tags: files, find, disk-usage

I am trying to display the top 20 largest files in a specific directory. I want to include all sub directories but not the actual directories themselves. (I only want  files.) I have been trying to find a way to do this and all the solutions I have found online do not work with the version on Unix I am using.

I have this so far:

`find /dir -type f -exec ls -al {} \; | sort -nr | head -n 20
du -a -g /dir/ | sort -n -r | head -n 20`

The fist gives me a list as follows:

```
file1.txt
file1.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

And so on. The second command gives me the following:

```
500    \path\
250    \path\to\
100    \path\to\directory\
```

And so on. The result I am looking for is:

```
500    \path\file1.txt
250    \path\to\file2.txt
100    \path\to\directory\file3.txt
```

And so on. I have tried the solutions from the following questions:

- [Finding largest file recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158289/finding-largest-file-recursively)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522269/how-to-find-the-largest-file-in-a-directory-and-its-subdirectories

I have also tried to follow this tutorial:

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-largest-file-in-directory-recursively-using-find-du/

Comment: You state that the solutions you have found don’t work on your UNIX version, but you don’t mention what it is. Please edit question to include this information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find dir/ -type f -exec du -a {} + | sort -nr | head -n 20
```

Comment: This doesn't output friendly. Some unknown numbers. Perhaps -h?

Answer (score 2):

In the `zsh` shell, the globbing pattern

```
/dir/**/*(.DOL[1,20])
```

would expand to the pathname of the 20 largest files in or below the directory `/dir` (with hidden names also being considered and symbolically linked files being ignored).

The parts of the glob qualifier `(.DOL[1,20])` means:

- `.`: Only consider regular files.
- `D`: Also consider files with hidden names (like the effect of `dotglob` in `bash`).
- `OL`: Order the result in decreasing order by file size (`O` = decreasing order, as opposed to `o` = increasing order; `L` = "length").
- `[1,20]`: Return the 20 first element that the glob expands to.

The `**` pattern matches "recursively", so `/dir/**/*` by itself would match any name in or below the `/dir` directory.

Using this with `ls`:

```
ls -l -f /dir/**/*(.DOL[1,20])
```

You would have to use `-f` with `ls` to stop it from sorting the list that it shows.

Or, to call `du` on the files:

```
du /dir/**/*(.DOL[1,20])
```