# E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)

Tags: linux, disk-usage

Is it possible to solve the space problem below as root user? Any idea which disk/folder is full, causing installation of new software impossible?

```
root@fba-bod-p1:/mnt/# apt install setuptools-scm
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.


root@fba-bod-p1:/mnt/# df -i
Filesystem                                Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs                                   16483401    1476  16481925    1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv        6553600  356895   6196705    6% /
tmpfs                                   16483401       1  16483400    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   16483401       4  16483397    1% /run/lock
1:2                                     63753378 2731153  61022225    5% /mnt/backup
/dev/sda2                                 131072     313    130759    1% /boot
/dev/sda1                                      0       0         0     - /boot/efi
158.39.32.194:/vol/vol_13122022_101029  31876689      96  31876593    1% /mnt/netapp1
158.39.32.196:/vol/vol_13122022_100726  31876689 2731057  29145632    9% /mnt/netapp2
tmpfs                                    3296680     143   3296537    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1                              610469888   18352 610451536    1% /mnt/encl_vol2
/dev/sdb1                              610469888 2227070 608242818    1% /home/fatima
tmpfs                                    3296680      74   3296606    1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs                                    3296680      68   3296612    1% /run/user/1004
tmpfs                                    3296680      76   3296604    1% /run/user/1027
```

df

```
Filesystem                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                    13G  1.3G   12G  11% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv        98G   98G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                    63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
1:2                                      37T   20T   18T  54% /mnt/backup
/dev/sda2                               2.0G  260M  1.6G  15% /boot
/dev/sda1                               1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
158.39.32.194:/vol/vol_13122022_101029   17T  5.5G   17T   1% /mnt/netapp1
158.39.32.196:/vol/vol_13122022_100726   20T   20T  117G 100% /mnt/netapp2
tmpfs                                    13G  116K   13G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1                                37T  8.3T   27T  24% /mnt/encl_vol2
/dev/sdb1                                37T   30T  5.4T  85% /home/fatima
tmpfs                                    13G   64K   13G   1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs                                    13G   64K   13G   1% /run/user/1004
tmpfs                                    13G   68K   13G   1% /run/user/1027
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s this one:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv        98G   98G     0 100% /
```

[Finding largest file recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158289/86440) will help you find the largest files, which may include candidates for removal.

If `ncdu` is already installed, you might find it useful to identify large directories:

```
ncdu -x /
```

You might find [Which installed software packages use the most disk space on Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40442/86440) useful too, although the answers there will probably involve installing additional software which will be difficult in your case.

Comment: cd /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
-bash: cd: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: Not a directory

Comment: In `df`’s output, the directory is the last entry on the line, in this case `/`.

Comment: @user2300940  As per the heading on the listing, the first column is the Filesystem (generally equivalent to the partition).