# Sort the files by size retrieved from a series of folders

Tags: bash, find, osx, sort, bsd

I retrieved all the pdfs in $HOME directory

```
$ find -E ~ -regex ".*/[^/].*.pdf"
```

It print more than 1000 files;
I intent to sort them by size and searched

```
$ stat -f '%z' draft.sh
184
```

I drafts the script:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/bash

OLD_IFS=IFS 
IFS=$'\n'

touch sorted_pdf.md

for file in $(find -E ~ -regex ".*/[^/].*.pdf")
do
    file_size=$(stat -c "%s" $file)
    ....

done > sorted_pdf.md

IFS=OLD_IFS
```

It's hard to work them together and get my result.
Could you please provide any hint?

I refactored the code

```
#! /bin/zsh
OLD_IFS=IFS 
IFS=$'\n'

touch sorted_pdf.md

for file in $(find -E ~ -regex ".*/[^/].*.pdf")
do
    # file_size=$(stat -c "%s" $file)
    printf '%s\n' $file(DoL)

done > sorted_pdf.md

IFS=OLD_IFS
```

but get error report

$ ./sort_files.sh

```
./sort_files.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./sort_files.sh: line 12: `    printf '%s\n' $file(DoL)'
```

Comment: That looks like BSD `find` for `-E` and BSD `stat` for `-f %z`, but then the `stat -c %s` indicates GNU `stat`, what system is it? Do you have to use `bash` or can you use other shells like `zsh`?

Comment: @StephenKitt, here there's an extra requirement that the file names end in `.pdf`. So it's different in that we need to sort files found by `find` (or other ways to find files by name).

Comment: ty, bsd on macos, but the refering question does not answer my question. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: no clue about BSD/macos, that is why I don't write an answer, but won't something like `find ... -printf '%s %P\n' | sort -n` work?

Comment: `syntax error near unexpected token '('` is a `bash` message, but in any case, `$file(DoL)` wouldn't make sense in `zsh` either. That's meant to be a _glob_ qualifier to sort the glob expansion, so doesn't make sense when applied to a single file.

Comment: @Stéphane the second answer on the duplicate I’d linked showed how to sort `find`’s output by size (using `-printf` on GNU `find`).

Comment: @StephenKitt, `printf` is GNU specific. The OP is on macOS.

Comment: @Stéphane which is also addressed alongside [the aforementioned answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88066/86440). (And when I closed the question, the macOS requirement wasn’t apparent — I agree as it stands currently, the question is better left open with your answer.)

Comment: printf resides on BSD @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @riderdragon, sorry I meant the `-printf` preficate of `find` is GNU-specific. The `printf` utility itself is standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort by size, you can use `zsh`'s glob qualifiers (`zsh` is installed by default on macOS, it even used to be `sh` there):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
printf '%s\n' **/*.pdf(DoL)
```

- `**/` is recurse globbing
- `(DoL)` is a glob qualifier, `D` to include dot files (hidden files) as `find` would, `oL` to sort the generated list by file `L`ength.

Note that `-regex ".*/[^/].*.pdf` doesn't make much sense.

That matches for instance on `/home/foo/pdf` , `.*` on `/home`, then `/`, then `[^/]` on `f` then `.*` on `oo`, then `.` on `/` and then `pdf`.

With `-regex`, with or without `-E`, you can use `-regex '.*\.pdf'` to match on `*.pdf` files, but you might as well use the standard `-name '*.pdf'`.

You could use:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec stat -f '%z %N' {} + |
  sort -n |
  cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

But that wouldn't work if there were file paths with newline characters.

With GNU utilities, you could do:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -printf '%s %p\0' |
  sort -nz |
  cut -zd ' ' -f 2- |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Note that if any of those `pdf` files are symlinks, it's the size of the symlink that is considered, not the size of the target of the symlink. To sort on the size of that target, change `DoL` to `D-oL` or add the `-L` options to `stat`. And with GNU `find`:

```
find -L . \( ! -xtype l -o -prune \) -name '*.pdf' -printf '%s %p\0' |
  sort -nz |
  cut -zd ' ' -f 2- |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

For case-insensitive matching, either replace `pdf` with `[pP][dD][fF]` or replace `-name` with `-iname` (not standard but supported by GNU and BSD `find`), or for `zsh`, enabled the `extendedglob` option and change `pdf` to `(#i)pdf` or enable the `nocaseglob` option.

Comment: I see. I desire to remind and cultivate the skills with regex.

Comment: so the problem could be solve with a plan to use `stat`, since shell script is not an OOP language, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to GNU `find`, `awk`:

```
$ find $HOME -iname "*.pdf" -printf '%s\0%p\n' | sort -h -t '\0' | awk -F '\0' '{print $2}'
```

This command:

- finds all files in `$HOME` having (case insensitive) pdf extension and prints size and path for each one;
- sorts the list by the first field using the `-h` option that enables human readable number comparison;
- prints the sorted paths.

Comment: `-printf` is a GNU `find` extension. It's not found in any other implementation yet. `-F '\0'` would typically not work with BSD `awk` either.